# AT+CIPSTART error closed

Tags: arduino, command-prompt, esp8266, at-command

```
  Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2409:4062:200e:142a:6569:e774:2948:3ef1
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2409:4062:200e:142a:909:453e:f942:3dc8
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6569:e774:2948:3ef1%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.119
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::7e91:22ff:fe97:1210%11
                                       192.168.43.1
```

i am connecting to my mobile hotspot

and my pc ip after connecting to hotspot is "192.168.43.119"

then i connected my esp8266 wifi module to my hotspot

```
Ai-Thinker Technology Co. Ltd.

ready
AT+CWLAP


ERROR
AT+CWMODE=3


OK
AT+CWLAP

+CWLAP:(3,"AndroidAP",-41,"7c:91:22:97:12:10",1,45,0)
+CWLAP:(3,"mona",-47,"04:b1:67:cf:10:2d",11,41,0)

OK
AT+CWJAP="AndroidAP","qwertyuio"

WIFI CONNECTED
WIFI GOT IP

OK
AT+CIFSR

+CIFSR:APIP,"192.168.4.1"
+CIFSR:APMAC,"5e:cf:7f:66:3e:2e"
+CIFSR:STAIP,"192.168.43.231"
+CIFSR:STAMAC,"5c:cf:7f:66:3e:2e"

OK
AT+CIPMUX=1
```

i want to connect to my localhost server of xampp which has the port number:1234

> http://192.168.43.119:1234/qq/index.php?val=100&&tval=20

but when from my esp8266 wifi module i connect it to localhost server it shows

```
OK
AT+CIPMUX=1


OK
AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","192.168.43.119",1234


ERROR
4,CLOSED
```

please help

Comment: Have you tested with `AT+CMEE=2` to see if you get more specific errors?

Comment: Have you tried other ID's for AT+CIPSTART?

Comment: what will be the difference if i change the id

Comment: @hlovdal its not  working its showing an error

Comment: Are firewalls and xampp configuration allow to accept connection from other newtwork clients? I see AP address "192.168.4.nnn" is in another subnet than "192.168.43.mmm" are connection queries routed correctly in between?